# Printing a table row in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I'm setting up a table with transactions, and want to be able to print each transaction separately with the click of a button (Basically print each row).
But can't seem to figure out how.

I've tried searching for it on google / stackoverflow but so far i cant find what i'm looking for.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Clientnumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LicensePlate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            <a>Gegevens Ophalen</a>
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clientnumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LicensePlate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="idButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Transactions</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

So in the end i want to be able to press a button and get a print preview of the row the button was in.

Comment: Where and how do you want the print preview? You mean to display data of that row in a popup and allow to print?

Comment: Yes display the row in a popup that allows to print.

Comment: It depends on many factors.  Do you want to open a totally new popup window?  Or do you just want a popup dialog (in the current window)?  The first is relatively easy.  You'd just create a new controller method and view to display just the one row and open a new window with that method being called.  The second is a lot more involved, and could be done in any number of ways.

Comment: So, where is your code to launch popup on button click? Please show that code and let us know the problem.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the second option is what i'm looking for.

Comment: @SivaGopal There is no code for that yet just the button.

Comment: @maikkrijgsman - So use a jquery dialog, and then use a jquery query to extract the row to populate your dialog.  You should be able to find examples of how to do a jquery dialog at the jquery site, and then figure out how to extract the html to use it.  This is a lot more work than can be simply answered in a question.  Stackoverflow works best to answer specific questions to specific problems, not asking for entire implementations.

Comment: @maik krijgsman did you try my answer? is it your requirement?

Comment: @HienNguyen i tried your anwser yes. unfortunately it wasn't the solution.

Comment: Please update detail your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample in javascript/jquery, use can apply to your cshtml file.

You need copy to HTML file to run this code.

```js
$('.idButton').on('click',function(){
     var printed = $(this).closest('tr').html();
     newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(printed);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="yourtable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Print</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
 <td><button class="idButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Transactions</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
 <td><button class="idButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Transactions</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td><button class="idButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Print Transactions</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```